# How can I get a count every 60 days using datepart()?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

The following query (on MSSQL) gives a correct answer to the question : how many IPs were collected on a monthly basis.
I would like to know how can I get the count per every 60 days?

```
select MIN(rowdate) min_rowdate, 
       MAX(rowdate) max_rowdate, 
       count(distinct IP), 
       DATEPART(MONTH, rowdate) month_
from t_tbl tl (nolock)
where rowdate between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-12-31 23:59:59'
group by DATEPART(MONTH, rowdate)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it using `DATEDIFF` and some simple maths:

```
select MIN(rowdate) min_rowdate, MAX(rowdate) max_rowdate, count(distinct IP),
       DATEDIFF(day, 0, rowdate) / 60 as day60
from t_tbl tl (nolock)
where rowdate >= '20150101' and rowdate < '20160101'
group by DATEDIFF(day, 0, rowdate) / 60
```

In this instance, it's using 1900-01-01 (what `0` gets converted to) as the start of the first 60 day period and all subsequent periods follow on from there.

If you want to use a different "fixed point" for the reporting periods, you'd put that in in place of `0` as the second parameter to `DATEDIFF`.

(I've also corrected your `WHERE` clause so that it doesn't exclude any events that happened *during* the last second of 2015, i.e. with a non-zero milliseconds value)

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I tried to put a date inside this line : group by DATEDIFF(day, '2015-01-01', rowdate) / 60 but It gives an error "...not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"
I'm rather new to SQL..

Comment: Why do you use `0` in `DATEDIFF` instead of explicit date? You saved few keystrokes here and the code will break when data type of `rowdate` is changed from `datetime` to `datetime2`. My concern is promoting bad practice here.